# Python - 'No suitable library found for ods' Pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, pyexcel

I wrote a script that opens and fetches values from `.ods` file and creates a new sheet and writes values using `pyexcel` and `pyexcel_ods3` . After converting into an executable I get this error `No suitable library found for ods` .

Code :

```
    sheet = pyexcel.get_sheet(file_name="sample.ods")
```

pyexcel - 0.4.2
pyexcel-io - 0.3.1
pyexcel-ods3 - 0.3.0
PyInstaller - 3.2.1

PS : I tried hidden imports and hook. I did some work and think its due to `__import__` in `manager.py` of`pyexcel_io`.

Comment: We have no idea what you wrote.

Comment: Sorry. This is my first time asking a question. My script works when running it as a script but  after converting it to an executable causes error as 'No suitable library found for ods' .

Comment: Trim down to a minimal example that exhibits the same behavior. Probably just an import and a printout of the package version will suffice. Then post it here (in your question, not in the comments).

Comment: Have you tried adding both `pyexcel` and `pyexcel_ods3` to `hidden_imports`?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the problem is not with using pyexcel to read the .ods file? Try using pyexcel_ods3 for fetching data from the .ods file:

```
sheet = pyexcel_ods3.read_data("sample.ods")
```

Once your script works with pyexcel_ods3, please refer to http://io.pyexcel.org/en/latest/pyinstaller.html for addition of hidden-imports.

I recently had similar issues but then I fixed my code and got a working .exe in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to tell PyInstaller to include the `pyexcel_ods3` library by adding it to the `hidden_imports` command-line parameter.

Another method to achieve the same goal is to explicitly import `pyexcel_ods3` in one of your app's code files. This will cause PyInstaller to recognize the library as a dependency.

Comment: Please reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983559/unable-to-use-pyexcel-xls-with-pyinstaller-python-executable-not-working-pyt. And what's missing is: `--hidden_imports pyexcel_ods3.ods`. See the note here: http://pyexcel-io.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#special-note-on-pyinstaller