# My exe. file created from pyinstaller doesn't work like it does when it was .py (Pyexcel problem)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyexcel

This is my first question
I am using *pyexcel* in my python(3.7.4) script and it worked well.
However after creating an exe file using **Pyinstaller** my exe file cannot run as it was .py

Here is the error while the program is running:
***(These problem didn't occur while I run .py script)***

```
  File "site-packages\pyexcel\core.py", line 110, in save_book_as

  File "site-packages\pyexcel\internal\core.py", line 39, in get_book_stream

  File "site-packages\pyexcel\plugins\sources\file_input.py", line 39, in get_data

  File "site-packages\pyexcel\plugins\parsers\excel.py", line 19, in parse_file

  File "site-packages\pyexcel\plugins\parsers\excel.py", line 40, in _parse_any

  File "site-packages\pyexcel_io\io.py", line 73, in get_data

  File "site-packages\pyexcel_io\io.py", line 91, in _get_data

  File "site-packages\pyexcel_io\io.py", line 190, in load_data

  File "site-packages\pyexcel_io\plugins.py", line 90, in get_a_plugin

  File "site-packages\lml\plugin.py", line 290, in load_me_now

  File "site-packages\pyexcel_io\plugins.py", line 107, in raise_exception

pyexcel_io.exceptions.SupportingPluginAvailableButNotInstalled: Please install pyexcel-xls
```

I already did all hidden import followed by https://pyexcel-io.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyinstaller.html and https://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyinstaller.html

This is my hidden import script used via command prompt

```
--hidden-import pyexcel.plugins.renderers.sqlalchemy --hidden-import pyexcel.plugins.renderers.django --hidden-import pyexcel.plugins.renderers.excel --hidden-import pyexcel.plugins.renderers._texttable --hidden-import pyexcel.plugins.parsers.excel --hidden-import pyexcel.plugins.parsers.sqlalchemy --hidden-import pyexcel.plugins.sources.http --hidden-import pyexcel.plugins.sources.file_input --hidden-import pyexcel.plugins.sources.memory_input --hidden-import pyexcel.plugins.sources.file_output --hidden-import pyexcel.plugins.sources.output_to_memory --hidden-import pyexcel.plugins.sources.pydata.bookdict --hidden-import pyexcel.plugins.sources.pydata.dictsource --hidden-import pyexcel.plugins.sources.pydata.arraysource --hidden-import pyexcel.plugins.sources.pydata.records --hidden-import pyexcel.plugins.sources.django --hidden-import pyexcel.plugins.sources.sqlalchemy --hidden-import pyexcel.plugins.sources.querysets --hidden-import pyexcel_io.readers.csvr --hidden-import pyexcel_io.readers.csvz --hidden-import pyexcel_io.readers.tsv --hidden-import pyexcel_io.readers.tsvz --hidden-import pyexcel_io.writers.csvw --hidden-import pyexcel_io.readers.csvz --hidden-import pyexcel_io.readers.tsv --hidden-import pyexcel_io.readers.tsvz --hidden-import pyexcel_io.database.importers.django --hidden-import pyexcel_io.database.importers.sqlalchemy --hidden-import pyexcel_io.database.exporters.django --hidden-import pyexcel_io.database.exporters.sqlalchemy --hidden-import pyexcel_xls --hidden-import pyexcel_xls.xls --hidden-import pyexcel_xls.xlsr --hidden-import pyexcel_xls.xlsw
```

and also I have installed these below.

```
pyexcel==0.5.15

pyexcel-io==0.5.20

**pyexcel-xls==0.5.8**

pyexcel-xlsx==0.5.8

PyInstaller==4.0.dev0+55c8855d9d
```

Thank you for every comment and answer!!

PS. I already installed **pyexcel-xls==0.5.8** and added --hidden-import pyexcel_**xls.xls**

UPDATE: The exe. still have the same problem. Should I post the Log of Pyinstaller or some of my imported libralies in my Python scripts?

Comment: Try to `import pyexcel.ext.xlsx`   and  `import pyexcel.ext.xls`

Comment: I added it in my script and again made it to exe, the script worked well but the exe still did the same result.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you download all files by following [these instruction](https://infotechmanagefactory.com/convert-xls-xlsx-python/)

Then, You have to specify the plugins in its hidden import options

```
 pyinstaller run.py   --hidden-import pyexcel_xls --hidden-import pyexcel_xls.xls   --hidden-import pyexcel_xlsx --hidden-import pyexcel_xlsx.xlsx
```

**#note** make sure that you use the [hidden import options](http://io.pyexcel.org/en/v0.5.11/pyinstaller.html) for your version and you can select your  version from the tab  `Read the Docs`

See [this](https://pyexcel-io.readthedocs.io/en/v0.3.4/#special-note-on-pyinstaller) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983559/unable-to-use-pyexcel-xls-with-pyinstaller-python-executable-not-working-pyt)

> If you  found a bug in PyInstaller  you can try downloading [the latest version](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/releases)

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
```

Comment: Yes, I am using that Pyinstaller zip, trying to figure out that the problem come out from the installer or my import method, I will update the result soon. Thank you very much.

Comment: I run the code and it works in python 3.7. What is the python version that you use

Comment: See this https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=160&v=lOIJIk_maO4&feature=emb_logo

Comment: Mine is 3.7.4, most of my main script is openpyxl and wx used for read database and calculate it, I just used the pyexcel to convert file type from xls to xlsx so that openpyxl can operate with the xlsx file, upfortunately the error occured in exe program.

Comment: I notes that you use an old version of `pyinstaller`  and you use the hidden import options for the latest version one. You have to install the latest version and use this http://io.pyexcel.org/en/v0.5.11/pyinstaller.html

Comment: Follow this instruction https://infotechmanagefactory.com/convert-xls-xlsx-python/